# PHP function echo text in <h1>,<h2>

Tags: php

It's just an example but can I fix this issue ?

```
function echoText($text){
    echo $text;
}

$text2 = echoText("Text");
echo "<h1>$text2</h1><br><h2>$text</h2><h3>$text</h3>";
```

But the result isn't `<h1>`, `<h2>` or `<h3>`, it's just simple text.

Comment: it's not really text though, but a heading. Maybe have an optional argument for the number. Also, having a function that only echoes rather than returns is restrictive.

Comment: I just needed to change 
function echoText($text){
    echo $text;
}
to
function echoText($text){
    return $text;
}
That was my issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is not *returning* the value, but *echoing* it out.

Try

```
function echoText($text){
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: I guess that's why it's called `echoText` ... what is the point of returning the passed param ?

Comment: @GabrielUhlíř I recommend you to change the function name to `getText()`.

Comment: @bsdnoobz I'd recommend he completely removes the function. It's completely redundant, it returns the parameter that is put into it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, you want this:

```
function echoText($text) 
{
    return '<h1>'. $text .'</h1>';
}
```

You can then use it:

```
$text2 = echoText('test');
echo $text2;
```

Comment: I want get school class of user in function with parametr $nick and just echo name of class getMyClass($_SESSION['nick']); (echo example: 1.A) and i need use this function over the server so i cant directly paste it into <h1></h1> in function, cause in other places is other styles

Answer (score 1):

`$text2` contains nothing (well, `null` technically), because `echoText()` returns nothing.
`return` a value from `echoText()` or otherwise assign a value to `$text2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
<?php
function echoText($text){
    echo $text;
}
$text2 = echoText("Text");
echo "<h1>".$text2."</h1><br><h2>".$text."</h2><h3>".$text."</h3>";

?>
```

You also need a return in your function.